# OSX Location Services cannot be enabled on Mountain Lion/Mavericks

Tags: xcode, macos

I had this problem since OS X Mountain Lion, and it remains after installing OS X Mavericks. When trying to use any App that requires my location, I am asked to enable Location Services. When I try to do so in System Preferences, I check the option and it immediately unchecks itself. (Note: I do have Wi-fi on).

The console reports the following, every time I try to check the option.

```
25/12/13 12:48:21.478 PM com.apple.preference.security.remoteservice[1595]: CoreLocation: CLInternalSetLocationServicesEnabled failed
```

Some users have attributed this problem to a faulty installation of iOS simulators via XCode. I have deleted XCode prior to the OS X Mavericks installation and it still does not work.

Does anyone have a clue of why this seems to happen?

Comment: did you ever find out what the problem is? i'm seeing something similar: as soon as the checkbox is clicked, the entire entry disappears. i'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: I am having a similar issue too.. Did u manage to figure out what went wrong?

Comment: Never figured out what was wrong.